# Query in oracle to extract data with prevoius daytime from certain dayime

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have name and daytime columns, so the same name could have multiple dates,
what would be the query in oracle to extract data with prevoius daytime from certain dayime, for example:

```
name daytime 
t12  12-Mar-2016
t12  14-Aug-2016
t34  13-Jan-2005
t34  18-Mar-2005
```

and I need:

```
name daytime 
 t12  12-Mar-2016
 t34  13-Jan-2005
```

thanks,
S

Comment: I am tempted to use min(date). Please clarify if that is not what you need.

Comment: I can't use min(date) since I need the one before certain date because can be  "t12  11-jan-2016" but I need "t12  12-Mar-2016".

Comment: Please add more data to clear this point. What do mean "before"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a min and group by

```
select name, min(daytime)
from my_table 
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the analytic function `row_number()` (or perhaps one of its close relatives, either `rank()` or `dense_rank()`, depending on the requirement. They will all produce the same output if there are no "ties", meaning you can't have two rows with the same `name` **and** the same `daytime`).

This is more often used with `rn = 1` to get the max `daytime`; if you want the "second" most recent `daytime`, use `rn = 2`.

The inner query returns one row for each row in the input table - with the same columns and values in each row and column, and with one column added, `rn`, showing the "rank" of each row within its group of rows with the same `name` (the column in `partition by`), ordered by `daytime` `desc`ending. Then it should be obvious what the outer query does.

```
with
     test_data ( name, daytime ) as ( 
       select 't12', to_date('12-Mar-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 't12', to_date('14-Aug-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 't34', to_date('13-Jan-2005', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 't34', to_date('18-Mar-2005', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select name, daytime
from   (
         select name, daytime, 
                row_number() over (partition by name order by daytime desc) as rn
         from   test_data
       )
where rn = 2
;

NAME DAYTIME
---- -----------
t12  12-Mar-2016
t34  13-Jan-2005

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, but possibly you want to use LAG. This will give you the date before any given date, assuming no duplicates. Borrowing mathguy's test data CTE, I tried:

```
with
     test_data ( name, daytime ) as ( 
       select 't12', to_date('12-Mar-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 't12', to_date('14-Aug-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 't34', to_date('13-Jan-2005', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 't34', to_date('18-Mar-2005', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select * from
(
select name, lag(daytime) over(partition by name order by daytime) daytime
from test_data
)
where daytime is not null
```